# SSIS send mail task error out specified string not in form req for an email address

Tags: ssis

My send mail task works fine for email ids like user@mydomain.com but it throws error for email ids like user@subdomain.mydomain.com.

is there any way i can make it work for such ids also?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't tried already, put the email in a variable and use the expressions to set it to the ToLine property.

Otherwise you could use a script task and send an email that way.  From what I can tell there are a lot of limitations with using the Send Email Task.

this should help:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.tasks.sendmailtask.sendmailtask.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The error with emails on subdomains is not specific to SSIS send mail tasks; it may be a limitation or rule on your SMTP server.

I am successfully getting emails from my SSIS Send Mail tasks, on my subdomain account